# Yii : Check if $criteria->compare from CDbCriteria matched the value or not

Tags: php, yii

Is there any way to check if the criteria specified was successful or not. I am trying to count the number of criteria that match and rank the results accordingly.

```
$criteria->compare('users.id', $id);
```

If the criteria above does produce a match do a `rank++`.

I found out that the statement above returns the `criteria` object itself. So, I am really confused in finding out a way to do this.

Will appreciate your help. Thanks.

**EDIT**

```
$count=YourModel::model()->countByAttributes(array('user_id'=>$id));
```

gives me total count of rows matched. I want to identify which particular row was a match and rank that row and sort the results according to the rank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `CDbCriteria` is just a criteria to search. This is not the data retriever. Its just set the conditions. To retrieve data you need to use `CActiveDataProvider` or `ActiveRecord`.
I dont know where do you want to use above code but i suggest the following code

```
$count=YourModel::model()->countByAttributes(array('user_id'=>$id));
```

or if you are using `CActiveDataProvider` then

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('YourModel',array(
'criteria'=>$yourCriteria
));
$count=$dataProvider->totalItemCount;
```

**EDIT:**

> I want to identify which particular row was a match and rank that row
>   and sort the results according to the rank.

Referring to your above question. Actually there is no way that you can use to identify that row. `Mysql` allows `Triggers` but you can only use them with statements like `INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE`. So if you want to modify database then you need to retrieve all the rows matching your criteria. Put them in foreach loop, rank them and save the model.

```
$models=YourModel::model()->findAll($yourCriteria);

if(isset($models))
{
  foreach($models as $model)
  {
    $model->rank=i;
    $model->save();
    i++;//rank number

  }
}
```

Comment: I get it `CDbCriteria` is just a criteria. But is there any way I could know which fields actually matched my criteria? Without storing all the data in an array/object and then computing everything on it.

Comment: Like you said `$count=YourModel::model()->countByAttributes(array('user_id'=>$id));` gives me total count of rows matched. I want to identify which particular row was a match and rank that row and sort the results according to the rank.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Cleared a lot of stuff. :)